# trouble using prestashop : blank page without errors

Tags: prestashop-1.5, dev-mode

I met some trouble while using prestashop.

I've also sent message to their forum but nobody seems to know that trouble.

the fact is that I have a blank page in my front office. 
the back office works fine.

I've set debug mode on like that

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```

I've also clear smarty cache, etc... and force recompilation, but it does not display any mistakes, so I do not know what to do to show mistakes.

Anykind of help will be much appreciable

Comment: Check PHP error log. If it’s not enabled, do so.

Comment: I have actualy nothing displayed